# Moment Bounds on Expectation of Constant to Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ which has support on $\{0,1,2,\dots, n\}$, and a constant $c \in (0,1)$.  Are the methods for computing bounds on $E[c^X]$ in terms of the moments of $X$?

For example, the lower bound $c^{E [X]} \leq E[c^X]$ can be demonstrated by applying $log$, exploiting monotonicity and concavity, and applying the exponential function to the result.

Is there a similar means to compute an upper bound on $E[c^X]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $t=-\log c>0$, then $c^X=e^{-tX}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(tX)^k}{k!}$, hence
$$ \mathbb{E}[c^X]=\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(tX)^k}{k!}\Big]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kt^k\mathbb{E}[X^k]}{k!}$$

(there is no issue with switching the sum and expectation because $X$ is bounded). This is an alternating series, so cutting it off at an even or odd $K$ gives you upper or lower bounds for $\mathbb{E}[c^X]$.

ETA: As A.S. points out, the expression $\frac{t^k\mathbb{E}[X^k]}{k!}$ may not be decreasing in $k$ for all $k$. But since $\mathbb{E}[X^k]\leq n^k$, the sequence will be decreasing for all $k>nt$.

Comment: The terms in the series are not necessarily monotone in absolute value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused as to why it must be that cutting it off at an even or odd $K$ must give an upper (resp. lower) bound.

Is this supposed to follow from the signs of the terms in the sum?

Comment: I've edited my post.